# Netsuite Mass Update Error

Tags: netsuite

I wrote a very simple (I thought) mass update to set the department on previous invoices so I could run a P&L report by department to see how our different lines of business are doing this calendar year.

The script is simply:

```
function updateInvoiceDepartment(rec_type,rec_id) {
var recInvoice = nlapiLoadRecord(rec_type,rec_id);
if (recInvoice.getFieldValue('job') != null)
    recInvoice.setFieldValue('department',4);
else
    recInvoice.setFieldValue('department',3);
nlapiSubmitRecord(recInvoice); 
}
```

However, when I run the script, I get the following error:

```
Error: RCRD_HAS_BEEN_CHANGED
Record has been changed
Stack Trace: nlapiCreateError(Controlco_Mass_Update.js$23323:1305)
nlapiSubmitRecord(Controlco_Mass_Update.js$23323:494)
updateInvoiceDepartment(Controlco_Mass_Update.js$23323:232)
<anonymous>(Controlco_Mass_Update.js$23323:234)
```

I'm a little confused. The error is that a record has been changed? But that's the point of the script, to change the records! I'm not sure why I'm getting this error or how to move forward?

Comment: are there any other script running in parallel ? is any other user simultaneously making a change to the record?

Comment: also, are you able to make the same change on same record from UI and does the always comes up every time or is it occassional?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely thing is interaction with a User Event script. One easy test is to replace nlapiSubmitRecord with:

```
nlapiSubmitRecord(recInvoice, {disabletriggers:true});
```

Comment: Ok, so that worked, but now I've got a whole other set of problems. Now it keeps failing over-and-over again because of "User_Error" because of problems with other fields on the invoices that have nothing to do with the field I'm trying to update. For example, something wasn't required when the invoice was created, but is required today, so any invoice without that filled in fails. Is there a way to skip the validation and just change the field I want to change?

Comment: Would advise you to look at the NetSuite Help documentation for `nlapiSubmitRecord`. It actually takes three parameters, one of which is `ignoreMandatoryFields` for exactly this purpose.

Comment: This doesn't work either: nlapiSubmitRecord(recInvoice, {disabletriggers:true}, {ignoreMandatoryFields :true});

Comment: Now it's complaining that "Total contribution for sales reps is 60.0%.  It must be 100%.  Please modify contributions."

Comment: All I want to do is update one field, it's laughable that it's this complicated.

Comment: The documentation on this is poor but when you use the object parameter you do it like: `nlapiSubmitRecord(invRec, {disabletriggers:true, enablesourcing:false, ignoremandatoryfields:true});`